# How to claim & configure Bitnami Docker Discourse data in Kubernetes Persistent volume?

Tags: kubernetes, bitnami, discourse, persistent-volume-claims

Currently I have bitnami discourse in docker and the data storing in pod, we scale up the pods from 1 to many. Now I am facing error with media uploads, the issue is the pods data are not in sync so I have to mount single volume and shared it between pods. But I want to do that persistent volume claim in kubernetes with the help of azure-storage-class not in docker volume.

Comment: Did you create any configuration? Maybe this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv) can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are using your own kubernetes manifest as bitnami aren't supporting discourse chart currently. Mainly, what I understand that you need is a volume that could be accessed by many PODs.

I think you would need `read-write-many` volume, this is not usually supported by cloud providers but let's give a try in azure.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I figure out that I need to a volume that can be accessed by many pods as a central data store. but I can't figure out how to do this, the exact statement is I need an azure-storage-class volume that can be claim by pods where that PV volume should be an container and the communication between pod and volume container should be inter-container. little help will be appreciated,Thanks in advance